# Postgis: How do I select every second point from LINESTRING?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

In DBeaver I have a table containing some GPS coordinates stored as Postgis LINESTRING format. 
My questions is: If I have, say, this info:

```
LINESTRING(20 20, 30 30, 40 40, 50 50, 60 60, 70 70)
```

which built-in ST function can I use to get every N-th element in that LINESTRING? For example, if I choose 2, I would get:

```
LINESTRING(20 20, 40 40, 60 60)
```

, if 3:

```
LINESTRING(20 20, 50 50)
```

and so on.

I've tried with ST_SIMPLIFY and ST_POINTN, but that's now exactly what I need because I still want it to stay a LINESTRING but just with less points (lower resolution).

Any ideas?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Have you tried using [`ST_DumpPoints`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) and applying a module `%` over the vertices `path`? e.g. every second record:

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT 
  ST_DumpPoints('LINESTRING(20 20, 30 30, 40 40, 50 50, 60 60, 70 70)') AS point
) 
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine((point).geom)) FROM j
WHERE (point).path[1] % 2 = 0;

           st_astext           
-------------------------------
 LINESTRING(30 30,50 50,70 70)
(1 Zeile)
```

Further reading:

- [`ST_MakeLine`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html)
- [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: Oh, wow... that was fast!

Thanks a lot, that works flawlessly :-)

Answer (score 0):

ST_Simplify should return a linestring unless the simplification results in an invalid geometry for a lingstring, e.i., less than 2 vertex.   If you always want to return a linestring consider  ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology .  It ensures that at least two vertices are returned in a linestring.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-) Yep, ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology results in LINESTRING, but I need every N-th element which it doesn't provide (it removes elements (based on the set threshold) with diff to the previous elements of less than the threshold, but not regular every N-th element). ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology is also very useful, but for a slightly different use-case

Comment: Cool.  It sounded from your question like maybe you were actually trying to generalize the line but wanted to ensure that a linestring was always returned based on your comment-  "but that's now exactly what I need because I still want it to stay a LINESTRING but just with less points (lower resolution)."

Comment: It was difficult to explain what I need... but thanks for your help :-)